# React - How can I get the values from my multiple input and send them to my input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using `<autocomplete>` as input field, I'm trying to log the values in my console to see if my submit method is working. Currently, I'm not able to submit anything, only empty data to my axios instance and not getting any Traceback errors to work with. My backend works fine, just struggling to send over the `data` from my form.

And I'm only trying send over the `symbol` from inputted values field to my backend,

```
const inputOptions = [
  { symbol: "ACN", company: "Accenture Plc", sector: "Technology Services"}
];
```

Check out my reproducible code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-lake-jvdyf?file=/src/App.js
{Without the axios instance}

Form:

```
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Grid>
            <form noValidate  onSubmit = { handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
              <Controller
              render={({ onChange ,...props }) => (
                <Autocomplete
                    {...props}
                    className={classes.inputBar}
                    id="stock_list"
                    name="stock_list"
                    multiple
                    options={inputOptions.companies}
                    filterOptions={filterOptions}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    defaultValue={[]}
                    onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data)}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol}
                    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.symbol === value.symbol}
                    renderOption={(option) =>
                    {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <span style={{ fontWeight: 500, fontSize: "20px", paddingRight: "1rem" }}>{option.symbol}</span><span style={{ color: "#C6C6C6", fontSize: "24px" }}> | </span><span style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}>{option.company}</span>
                        </>
                      )
                    }}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField 
                        {...params}
                        style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                        id="stock_list"
                        name="stock_list"
                        variant="outlined"
                        label="Companies"
                        className={classes.inputBar}
                      />
                       )}
                      />
                    )}
                    name="stock_list"
                    control={control}
                    defaultValue={[]}
                    onChange={([, data]) => data}
            />
            <Button 
              variant="contained" 
              color="primary"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
            >
              Add Stocks
            </Button>
            </form> 
        </Grid>
          </div>
```

I need to send the `symbol` values from the multi-input form above to my axios instance.

It's been proven difficult to do so with a `react-hook-form` and Material UI.

EDIT: I'm trying to extract the values from the input field, thanks to the comments I'm able to log to see what values of JSON are selected, but the form is not properly linked yet for submitting data as it seems im sending over an empty dictionary to my backend.

Here is my axios instance.

```
  const onSubmit = (data, e) =>
  {  
    console.log(data);

    axiosInstance
      .patch(url+ slug + '/', {
        stock_list: data.symbol,
      })
      .then((res) =>
      {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };
```

Comment: The first place to start would be console logging your handlers. For example, your onChange ```(e, data) => onChange(data) { console.log(data)  return data }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `type="submit"` to the submit button and remove the `onClick`, these changes will make the form submit function to be triggered when Add Stocks button is clicked

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
      Add Stocks
 </Button>
```

Comment: Hey Harikrishnan, thank you for the help. I had to re-word my post to make my objective a little more clear and concise. Your method allows me to see the values, but I'm afraid things are still not linked well within my form as I'm sending an empty dictionary to my backend

Comment: As you are using autocomplete to accept multiple values data in `onSubmit` method will be an array so `data.symbol` will be empty. If you need only one value then use autocomplete in normal mode

Comment: I need all of the values within form inputted by the user to be submitted.  Not sure what you mean with normal mode and autocomplete but I'm afraid thats out of the picture due to not involving all values.

Comment: `data.stock_list.map(list=>list.symbol)`  I hope passing this to your backend will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you sir I'm now getting symbol data forwarded to my backend.

Comment: After testing, I noticed that if someone were to type more than a couple letters, the component decides to crash, and provides this error: `Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined.`

Comment: I tried in code sandbox but was not able the recreate the issue

Comment: turned out to be a problem with something else. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the reproducible code and comes up with this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-firefly-n0ygq?file=/src/App.js

you can access the selected symbols in your submit method now.

Comment: When I visit your sandbox and click on a value I'm getting this error: `saveSymbols is not a function`

Comment: Sorry. the bug has been fixed.